# Trigger a Gradle task from a custom java plugin automatically for all modules of the project

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am writing a custom Gradle plugin in Java and it seems to work as I expect when I call explicitly the task it creates.

Now, the task is highly related to tests, so I would like it to execute automatically when the tests are executed (ideally, before the tests actually), but I am having 2 issues. Below is my plugin :

```java
public class MyCustomGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    public void apply(Project project) {
        MyCustomGradleConfig myCustomGradleConfig = project.getExtensions().create("myCustomGradleExtension", MyCustomGradleConfig.class, project);

        Task myCustomTask=project.getTasks().create("checkRules", MyCustomRulesTask.class, myCustomGradleConfig);

        archUnitTask.setGroup("verification");
        project.getTasks().findByName("test").dependsOn(myCustomTask);
    }
}
```

I build and deploy locally this plugin. When I declare and configure it in the build.gradle at the root of a multi-module project :

- if I forget to apply java plugin in the project, then the ´test´ task doesn't exist and myCustomTask can't be "attached" to it : is there a way to make sure the java plugin is declared when MyCustomGradlePlugin executes ?
- ´myCustomTask´executes, but only at the root of the project, where there's nothing interesting : if the project is a multi-module project, I need it to execute for all the modules. Ideally, I would like that the plugin takes care of it, to simplify to the maximum the config in the projects that will use it. How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to make sure the java plugin is declared when MyCustomGradlePlugin executes ?

Yes. You can either apply the `Java` plugin in your own plugin like this:

```java
project.getPlugins().apply(JavaPlugin.class)
```

Or you can conditionally add your task if the `Java` plugin exists like this:

```java
project.getPlugins().withType(JavaPlugin.class) {
    MyCustomGradleConfig myCustomGradleConfig = ...
}
```

> if theproject is amulti-module project, I need it to execute for all the modules.

You can achieve that by simply applying your plugin to each individual sub-project, e.g. through the `allprojects` method:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "your.plugin.id"
    myCustomGradleExtension {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also wrap all your plugin code in an `allprojects` block. In that case, from the user perspective, they apply your own plugin to the root and it will configure itself for all sub-projects.